# Favicon issue in html

Tags: html, favicon

I'm having issue with adding a favicon to my html file. I had added it earlier and it was working correctly, however now it has stopped working. I have added a link to an image at the top of my page and since I made that change, my favicon will no longer work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/71a9de138d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="Project.js"></script>
 

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">  <!--Favicon-->


  <!--Media Player-->
  <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
</head>
  <title>Tour</title>
 <header>
```

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Comment: Are you sure that favicon.ico is in the same directory as your HTML file? Also, the favicon can't just stop to work after, say 2 hours. Something must have happened.

Comment: Not related, but does you iframe work fine inside <head>? Also try to put <title> inside <head>.

Comment: Thank you for your help I have changed the location of the image used as the favicon and I now have it working with the following code:

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico.png" type="image/x-icon">   <!--Favicon-->
  <!--Media Player-->
  <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  <title>Tour</title>
</head>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title tag</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">  <!--Favicon-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/71a9de138d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="Project.js"></script>
     
  <!--Media Player-->
  <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
</head>
  <title>Tour</title>
 <header>
```

This is working at my end! Favicon should be at same hierarchy and exact name `favicon.ico`

Comment: Thank you for your help I have changed the location of the image used as the favicon and I now have it working with the following code: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico.png" type="image/x-icon"> <!--Favicon--> <!--Media Player--> <iframe src="open.spotify.com/embed/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe> <title>Tour</title> </head>